# Emailid and password validation using batchfile

Tags: windows, cmd, passwords, email-validation

I am trying to create batchfile which can check emailid and password
which is nothing but email and password validation

I want to take emailid ans password from user and on right email and password it will display Successful message and on wrong it should display Error message so my code is as given below

```
@echo off
echo Enter your Email id : 
set /p emailid=
echo Enter your password :
set /p pass=
goto CHECK

:CHECK
REM Here is a code for validation of Email id and password
REM if password is Right then it shold go to done or on wrong email or password it shold display Error Message
goto DONE

:DONE
echo %emailid% >> emailid.txt
echo %pass% >> pass.txt
echo Emaild is and password added successfully
goto CLOSE

:ERRORMSG
echo You Entered wrong username and password
echo password should be 10 chracter long and it shold contail one special character and one digit
goto CLOSE

:CLOSE
pause
exit
```

So can wny one guide me what i have to do for it.
Please help its very useful for me :)

Answer (score 0):

To validate credentials against an existing mailbox you need some 3rd party utility, such as

```
:CHECK
  getmail.exe -u %emailid% -pw %pass% -s pop3.yourserver.com 
  IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO :ERRORMSG
:DONE
```

Getmail is a Windows 95/NT console utility to download the contents of a pop3
mailbox.  It's ideal for scripts which need to get input from a mail message.
Using your language of choice, it allows you to add email capability to any
process (mail responders, or even lists).  Configuration information can be
saved in the registry.

GetMail is written by Tim Charron (tcharron@interlog.com)
It is available from http://www.interlog.com/~tcharron/getmail.html

Comment: I am not asking for credential validation i am talking about Email format.

Comment: Format of an e-mail message is specified in https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2822
It is a plain-text file with header lines, one separating empty line and the message body.